# Who are Alice and Bob?

Tags: terminology

Simply: who are Alice and Bob, and why are they mentioned in every Bitcoin-related article I read about that talks about Bitcoin transactions?

What is the history or mystery of these two?

Answer (score 6):

Fictional characters. Cryptography (and other) books use names like that often.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob

Answer (score 5):

Alice and Bob are [placeholder characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob) corresponding to the letters of the alphabet. They are used especially in computer science to describe use-cases or scenarios. The scheme is used because it's more convenient to say *"Alice sends money to Bob"* than to say *"Party A sends money to Party B"*. As each name has a different initial, diagrams can fall back to single letter labeling.

It's a well-known meme:

[image: Obligatory XKCD]
<sup>via [xkcd.com](https://xkcd.com/1323/)</sup>

The list usually goes something like this: **A**lice, **B**ob, **C**harlie, **D**ave, **E**rin, **F**rank,…

Other names are used to represent attacker types or other recurring roles:

- **C**arole, the oracle
- **E**ve, the eavesdropper
- **M**allory, the man-in-the-middle attacker with **mal**icious intent
- **S**ybil, the attacker with lots of identities
- **T**rent, the **tr**usted **ent**ity